# How to detect the subdomain from request in a gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to extend a gem file and create a library out of it. In the gem file I want to access the *request* parameter and find the specific sub-domain from it.

I have used request.subdomain over my application to access the sub-domain, but when i tried the same its results in an error.

This is how i access the local copy of gem in my project **Gemfile**

```
gem 'i18n-active_record', :path => '/home/myname/Downloads/i18n-active_record-master' ,:require => 'i18n/active_record'
```

This is the method i am trying to access the sub-domain

```
require 'rails'
require 'active_record'

module I18n
  module Backend

    class ActiveRecord
      class Translation < ::ActiveRecord::Base
        TRUTHY_CHAR = "\001"
        FALSY_CHAR = "\002"

        set_table_name 'translations'
        attr_protected :is_proc, :interpolations

        serialize :value
        serialize :interpolations, Array

        class << self
          def locale(locale)
            school_id = find_school
            scoped(:conditions => { :school_id => school_id.nil? ? nil : school_id, :locale => locale.to_s })
          end

          #for finding subdomain from request
          def find_subdomain
              subdomain = request.subdomain
              subdomain_id = Rails.cache.fetch([subdomain.hash,TRUTHY_CHAR.hash]){ School.find_by_subdomain(subdomain).id }
              return subdomain_id
          end


          def lookup(keys, *separator)
            column_name = connection.quote_column_name('key')
            keys = Array(keys).map! { |key| key.to_s }

            unless separator.empty?
              warn "[DEPRECATION] Giving a separator to Translation.lookup is deprecated. " <<
                "You can change the internal separator by overwriting FLATTEN_SEPARATOR."
            end

            namespace = "#{keys.last}#{I18n::Backend::Flatten::FLATTEN_SEPARATOR}%"
            scoped(:conditions => ["#{column_name} IN (?) OR #{column_name} LIKE ?", keys, namespace])
          end

          def available_locales
            Translation.find(:all, :select => 'DISTINCT locale').map { |t| t.locale.to_sym }
          end
        end

        def interpolates?(key)
          self.interpolations.include?(key) if self.interpolations
        end

        def value
          value = read_attribute(:value)
          if is_proc
            Kernel.eval(value)
          elsif value == FALSY_CHAR
            false
          elsif value == TRUTHY_CHAR
            true
          else
            value
          end
        end

        def value=(value)
          if value === false
            value = FALSY_CHAR
          elsif value === true
            value = TRUTHY_CHAR
          end

          write_attribute(:value, value)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want the gem to auto-detect the sub-domain and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to store the current request in a thread variable. It's not the best practice, since it's like using global variables, but in this case there may not be another way.

Example: set up a before filter in your controller (in `ApplicationController` if you want it for all controllers & actions) that does this:

```
Thread.current[:current_request] = request
```

Then in the gem, just access the variable, making sure to handle the case when the value is `nil`. The problem is that the gem now relies on the filter. There are probably ways to make it cleaner, but that's out of scope for this question.

EDIT

A possible way to make this cleaner is to provide a class method in your gem to set the current request. The method will handle the current thread. Example:

```
class I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation
  THREAD_KEY = :i18n_backend_ar_trans_request

  class << self
    def current_request=(request)
      Thread.current[THREAD_KEY] = request
    end

    def with_current_request(request)
      Thread.current[THREAD_KEY] = request
      yield
    ensure
      Thread.current[THREAD_KEY] = nil
    end

    # This is for your gem to access the value.
    # It's your choice whether to make it private, but I recommend doing so.
    private
    def current_request
      Thread.current[THREAD_KEY]
    end
  end
end
```

In your around_filter:

```
def your_filter
  I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation.with_current_request(request) do
    yield
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Kelvin. You saved my day. And I Made a change over filters. Instead of using before filter, I used around filter that would reset the value of Thread.current[:current_request] to nil. {  around_filter:find_subdomain                                                  def find_subdomain
    if request.subdomains.present?
      Thread.current[:subdomain] = request.subdomains
    else
      Thread.current[:subdomain] = nil 
    end

    begin
        yield
    ensure
        Thread.current[:subdomain] = nil
    end      
  end }

Comment: @DeepakA Sounds good. If this solved your problem, please accept by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the cause is that your `request` object is not accessible inside the gem. You can pass it as a parameter to `find_subdomain` method like this

```
def find_subdomain(request)
   subdomain = request.subdomain
   subdomain_id = Rails.cache.fetch([subdomain.hash,TRUTHY_CHAR.hash]){ School.find_by_subdomain(subdomain).id }
   return subdomain_id
end
```

You may want to dissect and explore this gem [subdomain-fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu/blob/master/lib/subdomain_fu/subdomain_fu.rb) for more

Comment: The request object cannot be passed over here because this method will be called when a translation miss is happening over the views. And this is handled by **I18n gem** . So I can't pass request object as a parameter. I was just going through the subdomain-fu gem. There also they seems to be using _request.sub-domains_ for finding out the sub-domain. Anyway I have to explore it more. Is there any other way to find the sub-domain.